# Grammaticality of "if you have time"

Tags: grammaticality

I would like to say something to the effect "if you are not (too) busy", but I would like to sound more neutral. This is why I chose "if you have time" but I am not sure if it sounds right in English in the following sentence:

> It would be lovely to see you if you have time.

Comment: That looks good.

Comment: It sounds fine to me, too. If you want to make it even more neutral (putting the arrangements on both of your shoulders), you could say, "It would be lovely to see you if we can arrange a time."

Comment: It looks fine to me too.

Comment: You may also say "if you have *the* time"

Answer (score 4):

Yes, "if you have time" is perfectly normal English. I suppose there's an implied "...to spare".

Comment: Does it right? : `If you have time by chance, please blah blah`.

Comment: "If you have time by chance..." sounds a little odd to me (British English), but grammatically I can't see anything wrong with it and it's perfectly understandable. I'd be more likely to say "if you happen to have time...".